# Why is mutate_at not creating a different name for new column when I pass it only one column in vars()?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I noticed an unexpected behavior of `mutate_at`. Suppose I have a data frame and a list of columns I want to mutate, like:

```
df1 <- data_frame(var1 = c(1,2,3,4,5,6),
                  var2 = c(1,1,1,2,2,2),
                  var3 = c(10,30,50,70,90,110))
variables <- c("var1", "var2")
```

I now apply `mutate_at` to create new factor versions of the columns defined in `variables`. By specifying "cat" in `list`, I am making sure the old versions are kept, and the new versions have the name of the old version plus "_cat":

```
df1 %>% mutate_at(vars(variables), .funs = list(cat = as.factor))
# A tibble: 6 x 5
   var1  var2  var3 var1_cat var2_cat
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <fct>    <fct>   
1     1     1    10 1        1       
2     2     1    30 2        1       
3     3     1    50 3        1       
4     4     2    70 4        2       
5     5     2    90 5        2       
6     6     2   110 6        2
```

However, if I apply `mutate_at` to only one column (in my case, my `variables` vector has only one element), the name of the new variable is only "cat":

```
variables <- c("var1")
df1 %>% mutate_at(vars(variables), .funs = list(cat = as.factor))
# A tibble: 6 x 4
   var1  var2  var3 cat  
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <fct>
1     1     1    10 1    
2     2     1    30 2    
3     3     1    50 3    
4     4     2    70 4    
5     5     2    90 5    
6     6     2   110 6
```

On some level, I understand why `mutate_at` is doing this: If you want to name one mutated column in any special way, just use `mutate` like `mutate(var1_cat = as.factor(var1))`.

However, in my case, I want to run the `mutate_at` operation over a number of data frames, for each of which I have a vector of columns to change. Crucially, these vectors might have only one element. So, would it not be better for `mutate_at` to show the same naming behavior no matter how many `vars` it receives?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't think this is the expected behavior (or at least shouldn't be), and the good news is that the newest version of [dplyr](https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2020/03/dplyr-1-0-0-is-coming-soon/) gets rid of this behavior. Currently you can install it using `remotes::install_github('tidyverse/dplyr')`, but should be on CRAN in the coming month or 2.

`mutate_at` (and other scoped verbs like `mutate_if`, `summarize_all`, etc.) has been replaced by the use of `across` within existing verbs, and this provides the behavior you are looking for.

```r
library(dplyr)

variables <- c("var1", "var2")

df1 %>% 
  mutate(across(all_of(variables), .fns = list(cat = as.factor)))
#> # A tibble: 6 x 5
#>    var1  var2  var3 var1_cat var2_cat
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <fct>    <fct>   
#> 1     1     1    10 1        1       
#> 2     2     1    30 2        1       
#> 3     3     1    50 3        1       
#> 4     4     2    70 4        2       
#> 5     5     2    90 5        2       
#> 6     6     2   110 6        2

variables <- c("var1")

df1 %>% 
  mutate(across(all_of(variables), .fns = list(cat = as.factor)))
#> # A tibble: 6 x 4
#>    var1  var2  var3 var1_cat
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <fct>   
#> 1     1     1    10 1       
#> 2     2     1    30 2       
#> 3     3     1    50 3       
#> 4     4     2    70 4       
#> 5     5     2    90 5       
#> 6     6     2   110 6
```

**Session info**

```r
sessionInfo()
#> R version 3.6.3 (2020-02-29)
#> Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
#> Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 17763)
#> 
#> Matrix products: default
#> 
#> locale:
#> [1] LC_COLLATE=English_United Kingdom.1252 
#> [2] LC_CTYPE=English_United Kingdom.1252   
#> [3] LC_MONETARY=English_United Kingdom.1252
#> [4] LC_NUMERIC=C                           
#> [5] LC_TIME=English_United Kingdom.1252    
#> 
#> attached base packages:
#> [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     
#> 
#> other attached packages:
#> [1] dplyr_0.8.99.9001
#>
#> loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
#>  [1] Rcpp_1.0.3        knitr_1.28        magrittr_1.5      tidyselect_1.0.0 
#>  [5] R6_2.4.1          rlang_0.4.5.9000  fansi_0.4.1       stringr_1.4.0    
#>  [9] highr_0.8         tools_3.6.3       xfun_0.12         utf8_1.1.4       
#> [13] cli_2.0.2         htmltools_0.4.0   ellipsis_0.3.0    assertthat_0.2.1 
#> [17] yaml_2.2.1        digest_0.6.25     tibble_2.1.3      lifecycle_0.2.0  
#> [21] crayon_1.3.4      purrr_0.3.3       vctrs_0.2.99.9010 glue_1.3.2       
#> [25] evaluate_0.14     rmarkdown_2.1     stringi_1.4.6     compiler_3.6.3   
#> [29] pillar_1.4.3      pkgconfig_2.0.3
```

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if there is an easy solution to this.

However, one way would be to apply the function based on `length` of `variables`.

```
library(dplyr)

if (length(variables) > 1) {
   df1 %>% mutate_at(vars(variables), list(cat = as.factor))
} else {
   df1 %>% mutate(!!paste0(variables, "_cat") := as.factor(!!sym(variables)))
}
```

Comment: Thanks - I have thought of something like that, but I was more trying to understand why `mutate_at` behaves the way it does

Comment: I think your understanding is correct on this. When you have only one variable, naming them with the name provided makes sense and when you have multiple variables in `mutate_at` you need the names to be unique hence a prefix is added. There is some explanation in `?mutat_at` under `Naming`.